# bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min,js, and ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js not resolving

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have a flask question, Im using bootstrap and I cannot get my 
 css/bootstrap.min.css and js/bootstrap.min.js files to resolve in Pycharm.  I placed both files in the appropriate css and js directories inside the static folder. My project is structured with the app file, static folder, templates folder, venv folder at the same level. Im using the bootstrap basic template to make sure its not a syntax error. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: How are you referencing the files in your template?

Comment: Remember to use url_for on Jinja2 example: <script src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/app.js')}}"></script>